# Xstring dealing with macros

Tags: macros, strings, xstring

I wrote the `\bib` command to reference authors in my thesis not using numeric or alpha references of `natbib`. It copies a piece of text, cut the first 60 characters (the width of my page} and put it together with the bibentry in the end of my work. Everything goes ok if there is no macros. I've used `xstring` and tried to expand, not expand...but I could not make it work. I appreciate any help.

```
\newcommand{\bib}[2]{#1 \pagenote{\cuttext{#1}}\bibentry{#2}}}

\newcommand{\cuttext}[1]{%
\expandarg\StrLeft{#1}{60}[\myleft]%
\expandarg\exploregroups\StrCount{\myleft}{ }[\mycount]%
\StrPosition[\mycount]{\myleft}{ }[\mypos]%
\StrLeft{\myleft}{\mypos}%
}%
```

Usage in the middle of my thesis text:

```
\bib{According to \citeauthor{last:2010} the best \textit{rock band singer} was bla bla bla}{last:2010}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`). I took the liberty to format you post a little. See [this link for more details on available formatting](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Also, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really hard to say anything definitive without MWE, but from the description of `xstring`, I doubt it can be made to work with commands like `\citeauthor`. It explicitly states in the doc to work with "strings of tokens".

I'd advise trying the `truncate` package.

Comment: Peter and Stephan, thank you very much for the help. The truncate package does the job.

Comment: @CaioBolzani In that case, maybe you could accept the question.